# Background loading slowly

Tags: css

I've tried to decrease the size/quality of my background picture, but still it loads rather slowly.

I often visit sites that have much higher quality backgrounds that load instantly

my site: http://staging.tabler.io/

How can I speed it up?

Comment: Your 'optimized' image is not so... optimized, actually... Open image in photoshop, choose 'save for web' option, choose desired quality and .jpg output - and you will see... You can get ~ 275kb image, and hold quality... for example...

Comment: Also, you could save it as progressive jpg to make the loading less noticeable. Then let it through a software like imageoptim

Comment: Do you have any kind of cache system. Reduce more the image and resave to JPG at 60%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is 1.1 MB so, contrary to the filename, it's not optimized.  Save it as a smaller file and/or optimize it with an app.

Also remember that the browser will cache the image.